# Python codestyle: does explicit better than implicit in this particular case?

Tags: python

Let's consider some class called `Image`.
It is supposed to:

1. Load an image from a file
2. Optimize it for internal use
3. Calculate an image mask.

### Usecase

```
icon = Image('img/btn_play_icon.png')

some_button.set_icon(icon)
```

So it is not planned that the methods of this class will be called directly.

### Implementation

1. Less explicit

```
class Image:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.load(filename)
        self.optimize()
        self.create_mask()

    def load(self, filename):
        self.img = ...

    def optimize(self):
        self.img = ...     # some optimization

    def create_mask(self):
        self.mask = some_module.get_mask_from_image(self.img)
```

2. More explicit

```
class Image:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.img = self.load(filename)
        self.img = self.optimize(self.img)
        self.mask = self.create_mask(self.img)
    
    ...
```

### Question:

I thought that there's no need to write more verbose and explicit implementation, because there's no usecase when user will need `icon2 = icon.optimize()` or something.
Is this the correct line of thought, or is the first implementation bad, and I should only use the second?

Comment: I think this question is very opinion based, but I'd say that the name of your methods should dictate their behaviour

Comment: If you call it `optimize()` then the first version is clearer. If you call it `optimized()` then I expect it to return something

Comment: If I read `x.load(something)` I expect `x` to be the subject of that sentence in a sense that `x` is loading something